# Java Program to calculate how many bounces it will take a ball to drop in 5% decrements. User will initially input the heigh

Tags: java, do-while

So I have to write a short Java program which will input of the height a ball is dropped from.  Assuming that on each bounce the height reached reduces by 5%, output the number of bounces that occur before
the ball stops bouncing.

I understand the logic of how to work this out but I cannot grasp how to put this into code.

I have some unfinished code, but just hit a brick wall.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```java
package doWhileLoops;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        int height = 0, noBounces = 0, fivePer = 0;
        fivePer = height /100 * 5;
        System.out.print("\n\tEnter the height in feet that the ball will be dropped from: ");
        height = key.nextInt();
        do {
            System.out.print("\n\tIt took  " + (height - fivePer));
            fivePer--;
        } while (height > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Be specific.

Comment: When it comes to the doWhile loop.  How can I write code to calculate how many decrements of 5% it will take and how to keep track of the number of bounces

Comment: If the loop stopping depends on the value of `height`, then `height` needs to change within the loop.

Comment: Ah Cheers, so I've got that now.  How can I code so that each decrement is 5% though?Been messing around with a few different variations and getting no where.  I've tried including the fivePer variable but not working

Comment: If the ball is dropped from a height of 100 feet, then, after the first bounce, will it rise to 95 feet? Assuming that it does, then after the second bounce will it rise to 90 feet or to 90.25 feet (i.e. 5% of 95)?

Comment: Mathematically the ball will never stop bouncing because you are assuming there are no losses. You should set yourself a limit for how close to zero you want to get. Also, using float/double is a much more appropriate choice since you are talking about physical simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculating the five percent of the height and subtracting at the end, you can just decrease the height by 5% everytime until it reaches 0.

What about

```
float height = key.nextInt();
int nBounces = 0;
while(height > 0){
    height *= 95 / 100; //decrease the height by 5%
    nBounces++; //add a bounce
}
System.out.print("\n\tIt took  " + nBounces);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Your calculation reduces the height **to** 5% not **by** 5%.  And, of course, per Zeno's paradox, it'll never stop bouncing (except I suppose you'll eventually get floating underflow).

Answer (score 0):

To get a feel of the algorithm, I mocked the following in Javascript. The important parts of the algorithm are:

- height reduction of 5% is implemented as `h = h * 95 / 100`
- there needs to be a terminating condition, i.e. threshold

When you run the algorithm you see that counter reaches 77. Why is it so high? Well, this is attributed to the fact that (1) a height reduction of 5% is unrealistic, in practice, a figure of 50% is more realistic, (2) in practical physics, there is a drag that causes it to diminish faster and eventually rest. With zero resistance, theoretically, something could bounce forever - hence, it is important that the question is improved with a terminating condition.

To demonstrate the algorithm, I did write it in Javascript not Java, so that you can run it in the browser.

```js
let h = 50;        // initial height, say 50cm
let threshold = 1; // threshold height, say <= 1cm
let count = 0;     // counter for bounces
while (h > threshold) {
    h = h * 95 / 100; // 5% height reduction
    count++;
    console.log(count, h);
}
```